# Query returning only empty value in java

Tags: java, oracle

I am using java to connect with oracle.This is the code which I have used

```
public List<FavouriteShop> getmyfavouriteshop(String username) {
    List<FavouriteShop> res=null;
    res = this.getJdbcTemplate().query("select * from(Select tbl_orderdetails.branch_name as myfavourite,tbl_orderdetails.branch_id as branch_id from tbl_orderdetails inner join tbl_ordermaster on tbl_orderdetails.order_master_id=tbl_ordermaster.ordermasterid where tbl_ordermaster.user_id='"+username+"' group by tbl_orderdetails.branch_name,tbl_orderdetails.branch_id order by count(tbl_orderdetails.branch_name) desc) where rownum<=3", new MyFavourite());   
    return res;
}

private class MyFavourite implements RowMapper<FavouriteShop> {
    public FavouriteShop mapRow(ResultSet rs,int i) throws SQLException {
        FavouriteShop g=new FavouriteShop();
        g.setBranch_id(rs.getString("branch_id"));
        g.setMyfavourite(rs.getString("myfavourite"));
        return g;
    }
}
```

I tried to execute same query in oracle I am getting output but not here and I am getting only empty result.

Comment: BTW, using inline creation of queries is a good receipe for SQL injection

Comment: can you explain about sql injection

Comment: You did not use a parameterised query here, so that your application will be vulnerable to the user who can easily inject malicious query through text box/ something... Read here to know more about it.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a possible SQL injection. You can avoid this by giving `username` as an argument to [`query`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper%29)

```java
this.getJdbcTemplate().query("select * from (... where tbl_ordermaster.user_id=? ...) where rownum<=3",
                              new Object[]{ username }, new MyFavourite());
```

---

A possible reason for the empty result might be

```
... where tbl_ordermaster.user_id='"+username+"' ...
```

Usually, `user_id` is an integer value, but you compare it to a `String` and enclose it in quotes. Passing `username` as an argument to `query` as shown above, should already take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is not the same query or not the same database :)

Extract your query text to separate variable, print it to logs. Then copy-paste from logs to sql developer.

And check database and user name.

Also, it is possible that you inserted that entries but forgot to add COMMIT.

Comment: small comment - your RowMapper implementation should be `private static` and can be cached in private field.

Comment: if you have checked the logs, can you cross check the actual query being executed ?